# Why are more energetic events less likely

Tags: energy

So I was watching this very interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htf0XR6W9WQ) by DoS and noticed all the downward sloping lines in his Doomsday graph, and started wondering what is the fundamental reason behind those expected trends. I mean, it seems obvious that bigger hurricanes are rarer than smaller ones but I couldn't quite point out what law of physics/postulate implies this. Is it entropy, the second law in some way? Or just because we assume the energy in a semi-isolated system if finite therefore more energetic events are necessarily less common? But that doesn't really explain other curves for climate change or resistant bacteria. Or even why the volcanoes one is a plateau. I'm not sure if this is even the most appropriate SE to post this on, or if I'm grasping at straws, but I couldn't help getting annoyed that as a physics grad I couldn't explain the shape of those curves by anything else than an intuition. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More energetic events require more energy to get started. The "activation energy" is higher. It is less likely to get that activation energy, hence the events themselves are also less likely.

You might be familiar with plots such as [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Activation2_updated.svg), which shows how catalysis works. You might also remember plots of quantum tunneling. The higher the barrier, the less likely it is to tunnel through.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of the principle of exponential decay in likelihood for more energetic events is in order? I've read that Boltzmann distribution maximizes the entropy, so it seems like that should be the base of any explanation; I'd like to get a feel for why a Boltzmann distribution *should* maximize entropy.

Comment: This is a well-known "rule of thumb" in the natural world, where something twice as (big, important, strong, severe) is generally about half as probable. This "rule" has a name which I will try to remember, and if I do I'll post it as an answer here.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I would very much like to know what it is!